# Displaying result from array according to other array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 array in my database that is coming from a form a form

array result form database

- staff names  דרור שליט,לנה שליט
- start date  2019-02-01,2019-02-14
- end date  2019-02-13,2019-02-27

I would like to check if the current date is in the range of the two arrays and if there is a match display the name of he staff member from the staff array 
for example if I take only the first value of each array the result will be

- staff name  לנה שליט
- start date  2019-02-01
- end date  2019-02-13

This is what I tried but that doesn't give me the proper result :

```html
$neword = "SELECT `order_id` , `item`,`staff_name`, `staff_start_d`,`staff_end_d`,`item_sn`,`status`, DATE_FORMAT(`stamp` , '%d-%m-%Y'  ) as `stamp` FROM rent ";
$userord = mysqli_query($link, $neword);
foreach ($userord as $myitem);

  <?php foreach ($userord as $myitem) : ?>
<?php
      $s_dates = array($myitem['staff_start_d']);
      $e_dates = array($myitem['staff_end_d']);
      $names = array($myitem['staff_name']);
      $start = date("Y-m-d");


      foreach($s_dates  AS $date_s) {
          $timestamp = strtotime($date_s);
          if($timestamp == $start ) {
              echo "1";
          }else{
              echo "no1";
          }
      }

      foreach($e_dates  AS $date_e) {
          $timestamp = strtotime($date_e);
          if($timestamp == $start ) {
              echo "2";
          }else{
              echo 'no2';
          }
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: If you want to check if a date is in a given _range_, then why are you comparing for _equality_? That would get you matches only of the date happened to be the exact start or end date of the interval, but not if it was anywhere in between. And to check if a date was in any of those intervals, you would need to check it against start _and_ end date of an interval - right now, you are checking it against all the start dates first, and then against all the end dates after - does not make much sense either.

Comment: You should really start with a better data structure. This should be _one_ array (that you can then loop over), that contains intervals (start _and_ end date) as its elements.

Comment: so you recommend to put all the data in the same column? like staff_name,start_date,end_date?

Comment: I am talking about your arrays here, not your database structure. (Those do not necessarily need to match 1:1.)

Comment: can you pleas give me an example for better data structure?

Comment: I already did, didn’t I? _“one array, that contains intervals (start and end date) as its elements.”_

Comment: code example if you can.

Comment: No, not for something this trivial - make an attempt first, and show us. But depending on what you need and how exactly you have your data stored in the database, it might make more sense to let the database do this kind of filtering already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert date in timestamp and then you can check as below code:

```
$s_dates = explode(",", $myitem['staff_start_d']);
$e_dates = explode(",",$myitem['staff_end_d']);
$names = explode(",", $myitem['staff_name']);
$start = date("Y-m-d");


foreach($s_dates as $key => $date_s) {
    if (strtotime($start) >= strtotime($date_s) && strtotime($start) <= strtotime($e_dates[$key])) {
        // show your employee details here as
        echo $date_s.'<br/>';
        echo $e_dates[$key].'<br/>';
        echo $names[$key].'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Also, I am assuming that you are making value array which is useless. Hope it helps you.

Comment: thank yo for this comment , just for test if i change the strtotime($myitem['staff_start_d']) to the current date i get a result but the full array and not only the result that mach the date inside the array.. any advice?

Comment: _“You need to convert date in timestamp”_ - no, you don’t _need_ to; the input values are in a _sortable_ format already, so the necessary checks can be done doing string comparison.

Comment: can you give me a code example based on Rohit Mittal answer?

Comment: @drorshalit I dont understand your comment. can you show your $userord vardump so I can understand better.

Comment: array(8) { ["order_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["item"]=> string(25) "חמישה בלונים 5" ["staff_name"]=> string(33) "דרור שליט,לנה שליט" ["staff_start_d"]=> string(21) "2019-02-01,2019-02-14" ["staff_end_d"]=> string(21) "2019-02-13,2019-02-27" ["item_sn"]=> string(11) "balonim001 " ["status"]=> string(1) "1" ["stamp"]=> string(10) "25-02-2019" }

Comment: Check yoru staff_start_d value. It is not a valid date?? is it that you are concating two dates??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188994/discussion-between-dror-shalit-and-rohit-mittal).